# Sending API data in Gatsby to be used in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to send API data being called from my index.js to my ChartData.js. index.js is a page and ChartData.js is a component in Gatsby, so to begin with I could not figure out if Gatsby's Link to="" function only work from one page to another or if it can send data from a page to a component.

The issue is when I try to access the sent data from index.js to ChartData.js in the line `{props.location.state.companyName}` I am getting the error: `TypeError: props.location is undefined`

I plan to switch out `labels: ['x', 'y']` for something like `labels: [{props.location.state.companyName}, {props.location.state.symbol}` etc. I am not sure if this would be the correct syntax either.

A more detailed explanation here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=No9cqzqlKS0&feature=youtu.be

index.js:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import axios from "axios"
import "../css/style.css"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import { symbol } from "prop-types"
import ChartData from "../components/ChartData"

export default class index extends React.Component {
  state = {
      companyName: "",
      previousClose: "",
      marketCap: "",
      change: "",
      symbol: "",
      topStocks: [],
      Yearweekhigh: "",
      Yearweeklow: "",
      avgTotalVolume: "",
      peRatio: ""
      

  }


  componentDidMount() {
    const API_KEY = '*******************';
    axios.get(`https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/previous?token=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(res => {
        
        console.log(res)

        const topStocks = res.slice(1);
        this.setState({ topStocks })

      })
  }
  

  clickHandler = (event) => {
          if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          const query = event.target.value;
          const API_KEY = '*******************';
      axios.get(`https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${query}/quote?token=${API_KEY}`)
          .then(res => {
              const companyName = res.data['companyName'];
              this.setState({ companyName })

              const previousClose = res.data['previousClose'];
              this.setState({ previousClose })

              const marketCap = res.data['marketCap'];
              this.setState({ marketCap })

              const change = res.data['change'];
              this.setState({ change })

              const symbol = res.data['symbol'];
              this.setState({ symbol })

              const Yearweekhigh = res.data['week52High'];
              this.setState({ Yearweekhigh })

              const Yearweeklow = res.data['week52Low'];
              this.setState({ Yearweeklow })

              const avgTotalVolume = res.data['avgTotalVolume'];
              this.setState({ avgTotalVolume })

              const peRatio = res.data['peRatio'];
              this.setState({ peRatio }) 


          })
      }
  }



  render() {
      return (
          <Layout>
              <div class = "main-div">
                  <input type="search" class="main-search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)}/>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Ticker-Symbol</th>
                      <th>Market Cap</th>
                      <th>Previous Close</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                      <Link to='/details/' state={{

                        setState: this.state.symbol, 
                        companyName: this.state.companyName, 
                        previousClose: this.state.previousClose,
                        marketCap: this.state.marketCap,
                        change: this.state.change,
                        Yearweekhigh: this.state.Yearweekhigh,
                        Yearweeklow: this.state.Yearweeklow,
                        avgTotalVolume: this.state.avgTotalVolume,
                        peRatio: this.state.peRatio

                        }}>
                          {this.state.symbol}</Link>


                          <Link to='/ChartData/' state={{

                          setState: this.state.symbol, 
                          companyName: this.state.companyName, 
                          previousClose: this.state.previousClose,
                          marketCap: this.state.marketCap,
                          change: this.state.change,
                          Yearweekhigh: this.state.Yearweekhigh,
                          Yearweeklow: this.state.Yearweeklow,
                          avgTotalVolume: this.state.avgTotalVolume,
                          peRatio: this.state.peRatio

                          }}></Link>
                        </td>
                      <td>{this.state.marketCap}</td>
                      <td>{this.state.previousClose}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
              <div>
                {
                  this.state.topStocks.length && this.state.topStocks.map(stock => (
                  <h1>{stock.symbol}</h1>
                  ))
                }
              </div>
              <ChartData />
          </Layout>
      )
  }
}
```

details.js

```
//import { Link } from "gatsby"
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import "../css/style.css"

const Details = props => {
  const [yourState, setYourState] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {

  }, []);

  return  <Layout>
    <div>
    <h1 class="details-company-name">{props.location.state.companyName}</h1>
    <div class = "details-div">
      <div class="details-div-1">
        <p>Open {} </p>
        <p>High {} </p>
        <p>Low {} </p>
        <p>52 WK HIGH <h2>{props.location.state.Yearweekhigh}</h2> </p>
        <p>52 WK LOW <h2>{props.location.state.Yearweeklow}</h2> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="details-div-2">
        <p>VOLUME</p>
        <p>AVG VOL <h2>{props.location.state.avgTotalVolume}</h2> </p>
        <p>MKT CAP <h2>{props.location.state.marketCap}</h2></p>
        <p>P/E RATIO <h2>{props.location.state.peRatio}</h2></p>
        <p>DIV/YIELD</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      </Layout>;
    };

export default Details;
```

ChartData.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";


const ChartData = props => {
    const [yourState, setYourState] = useState('');

    const chart = () => {
        setYourState({
            labels: ['x', 'y'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    level: 'level of xyz',
                    data: [22, 55]
                }
            ]
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        chart()

    }, [])
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            {props.location.state.companyName}
            <div>
                <Line data={yourState}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ChartData;
```

Comment: Is  `<ChartData />` a component that is rendered on the `index` page? If so, you should pass the relevant props to `<ChartData />`  instead of `<Link>`

Comment: React docs are a good place to check https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html, https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props

Comment: i want ```<ChartData />``` to be a component that will be rendered on the ```details``` page.

Comment: If you want to render it on the `details` page, the same applies. The data is available on `props.location.state`. You can pass some (or all of this data) as props to `<ChartData />`

Comment: Also, remember to generate a new api key, as it was made visible on your youtube video :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a quite a bit going on here that needs clarification. You mention graphql in the title, but there's no graphql in your code.

You are using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to fetch data at runtime in the [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method, and then setting the result to state.

I assume that once you have that data, all you want to do is pass it to your chart component so that it can render itself on the index page.

Consider the following example which does the same thing; Fetches some data from the [Rick & Morty api](https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation), sets the results to state, and passes the relevant part of that state via props directly to the `<Characters />` component.

From there, the `<Characters />` component has everything it needs in order to render. (It has no state, and is not concerned about where the data actually came from).

```
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Characters from './Characters'

const api = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/";

class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(api)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        json => {
          console.log(json)
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            data: json.results
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, data } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <Characters data={data} />
      );
    }
  }
}

export default IndexPage;
```

---

```
// Characters.js

import React from 'react';

class Characters extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.data.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <dl>
              <dt>Name:</dt>
              <dd>{item.name}</dd>
              <dt>Species:</dt>
              <dd>{item.species}</dd>
              <dt>Status:</dt>
              <dd>{item.status}</dd>
            </dl>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Characters;
```

[Codesandbox Example using functional components and hooks](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-liskov-0ktnd?file=/src/App.js)

---

[Gatsby’s `<Link>` component](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/) allows you to link *between pages* (and does some other stuff like prefetching resources, and can share data between pages). As you are rendering the `<ChartData />` component on the `index` page, this is not required to solve your problem.

Using `<Link>` with state works because `details` is a gatsby page. As `<ChartData> is not a page, you can't *link* to it.`

Comment: I apologize I did not mean graphql I meant Chart js. I am trying to send API data from index.js to ChartData.js and use {props.location.state.MYSTATE} as labels and datasets.

Comment: I made a video explaining the issue here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=No9cqzqlKS0&feature=youtu.be I also updated my code with details.js to show how this is working already but I just need it to work in ChartData.js then implment the api data (ie {props.location.state.companyName}) into the graph.

Comment: The example in this answer does exactly what you need.